# Why does the Ajax $.post() function return data with </br>?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send information to the PHP function and return data from that function.But the data that return contains `</br>` at the beginning.

```
<script>


$('#addmenu').click(function (e) {
    $('#menuform').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var title=$('input[name=title]').val();
        var link=$('input[name=link]').val();
        var parentid=$('select[name=parentid]').val();
        var url=$(this).attr('action');
        var data={'title':title,link:link,'parentid':parentid};
        $.post(url,data,function (msg) {
            alert(msg);

        })

    })
})
```

With this code, the information entered in the form is sent to the php method by clicking the submit button.
My php function:

```
    public function Insert(){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $link=$_POST['link'];
    $parentid=$_POST['parentid'];
   
    
        try {
            $this->modelDb->insert($title, $link, $parentid);
            echo 1;
        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo 0;
        }

}
```

But what alert (msg) indicates is:

```
</br>1
```

I checked everything but it does not work. It takes the input function correctly. But msg contains `</br>` in any case, even if the function does not return anything.

Comment: Your PHP code is outputting `</br>` *somewhere*.

Comment: </br> is not even a valid tag

Answer (score -1):

The function you quoted isn't the entry point to the PHP program (it can't be, PHP doesn't work like that, the entry point has to be a program not a function in one). Something is echoing that value before the Insert function is called.